# Is this error due to parallel processing of SQL leading to a Truncation error?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting this error and I know that it is because of the LAST_NAME field.

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 4
>    String or binary data would be truncated.
>    The statement has been terminated.

Here is the SQL

```
INSERT INTO Rpt_Authority_Exceeds_Guidelines
(
  Last_Name --DECLARE to be CHAR(20)
, First_Name
, Band_Level
, emp_status
, Exp_Description
, Amount
, CSG
, Above_CSG
, Below_CSG
, AOR1_Desc
, AOR2_Desc
, AOR3_Desc
, AOR4_Desc
, Updated_By
, Update_Date
)

SELECT
    soa_ees.Last_Name         --DECLARE to be Varchar(50)
  , soa_ees.First_Name
  , soa_ees.job_gradf         AS Band_Level
  , soa_ees.emp_status
  , soa_amounts.[description] AS Exp_Description
  , soa_eeamounts.Amount
  , soa_defaults.Amount       AS CSG
  , 0                         AS Above_CSG
  , 0                         AS Below_CSG
  , soa_ees.AOR1_Desc
  , soa_ees.AOR2_Desc
  , soa_ees.AOR3_Desc
  , soa_ees.AOR4_Desc
  , soa_eeamounts.[uid]       AS Updated_By
  , soa_eeamounts.lastchange  AS Update_Date
FROM
    soa_eeamounts
        INNER JOIN soa_ees
            ON soa_eeamounts.EmployeeId = soa_ees.emp_id 
        INNER JOIN soa_defaults
            ON soa_eeamounts.code = soa_defaults.code
            AND soa_ees.job_gradf = soa_defaults.job_grade
        INNER JOIN soa_amounts
            ON soa_eeamounts.code = soa_amounts.code
WHERE
    soa_eeamounts.amount > soa_defaults.amount
    OR (soa_eeamounts.code = 'EXT' AND soa_eeamounts.amount > 5000000)
```

What is puzzling me is that length of the longest LAST_NAME that meets WHERE condition is only 16. However, if I remove the WHERE clause, there are LAST_NAME values whose length would exceed the length of the Target column, which is defined as CHAR(20).

I have seen situations with SQL Where the WHERE Clause is applied AFTER some function that really needed the filter to be applied first but I never expected this. SQL Server appears to be inserting the record into the target table BEFORE The WHERE clause is applied with the intention to later remove those that do not meet the filter criteria but the truncation error occurs on the INSERT before the WHERE clause could ever be applied to remove the records that were temporarily inserted.

I believe I proved it by confirming that if I add the query hint at the end

```
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

to run on one processor, it works, but I can't believe my eyes.

Did I come to the right conclusion or is something else going on?

Comment: Please post the execution plan. Maybe there is a spool into a temporary table. Also, what is your version of SQL Server, can you use trace flag 460?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean that the longest `LEN(LAST_NAME)` is 16. The `LEN()` function doesn't take trailing whitespace into account. How is `soa_ees.LAST_NAME` defined? If it's `char(50)`, for example, then `DATALENGTH(soa_ees.LAST_NAME)` will be 50 and overflow your `nchar(20)` column.

Comment: Also provide the table details of the one you are trying to insert to?

Comment: The data type definition of the source LAST_NAME, Varchar(50), column and dest LAST_NAME column, CHAR (20).  are noted as comments in the SQL itself. I'll post the execution plan soon.